# module 'tensorflow_federated.python' has no attribute 'federated_computation'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

I follow the instructions in the github that says to install Tensorflow Federated with Collab we need to install version 0.20.0 but I get this error when I try to run the toturials.

```
!pip install --quiet tensorflow-federated==0.20.0 # The latest version of tensorflow-federated is not working with the colab python version
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio
```

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import collections

from six.moves import range
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
# from tensorflow import compat

from tensorflow_federated import python as tff

np.random.seed(0)

tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()

tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')()
```

Error:

```
module 'tensorflow_federated.python' has no attribute 'federated_computation'
```

What is the problem I don't understand? How can I install it on google colab. There is no resource for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need to import this

```py
from tensorflow_federated import python as tff
```

instead of

```py
import tensorflow_federated as tff
```

According to the [Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_computation), the `federated_computation` was under `tensorflow_federated` directly.